# SQLAlchemy - Mapping self-referential relationship as one to many (declarative form)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to map a Tag entity using declarative method with SQLAlchemy. A tag can have a parent (another Tag).

I have:

```
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, label, parentTag=None):
        self.label = label
```

How can I add the "parent" relationship?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You add a `ForeignKey` referencing the parent, and then create a relationship that specifies the direction via `remote_side`. This is documented under [adjacency list relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html). For declarative you'd do something like this:

```
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'))

    parent = relationship('Tag', remote_side=[id])
```

If you want the reverse relation also, add `backref='children'` to the relationship definition.

Comment: That url moved to http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html?highlight=adjacency%20list#adjacency-list-relationships

Comment: The url moved again (to http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html)

Comment: Can I use Tag.parent.parent.label for grandparent's label?

Answer (score 8):

If you need children, you need to use `uselist`:

```
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'))

    children = relation('Tag', remote_side=[id], uselist=True)
```

Comment: is this ' relation ' is something primitive to 'relationship'.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Company(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'
    companyName = db.Column(db.String(50))
    contactPerson = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    mobile = db.Column(db.String(20))
    parentID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('companies.id'))  # parent company ID
    childrenCompany = db.relationship('Company', remote_side='Company.id',
                                    backref=db.backref('children_company'))  # parent Company
```

### use:

```
In [2]: company_query = Company.query.get_or_404(1)

In [3]: company_query.children_company
Out[3]: 
[<app.models.user.Company at 0x10f527850>,
 <app.models.user.Company at 0x10f527c10>]
```

Answer (score 0):

`parent = relation('Tag')` — see http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/ext/declarative.html#configuring-relations.

Comment: I try this, but give me an error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Tag.parent.  Specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.  If this is a many-to-many relationship, 'secondaryjoin' is needed as well.

Thanks

Comment: late comment, you need `parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'))` to avoid that error