# Many to one relationships within table in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a model class Document which optionally contains 2 pointers to 2 other elements of the same class (table).

- original_id which should hold the index of another member of the table which is "the" original version of the document (can be null).
- first_id which should hold the index of another member of the table which is the "first" document that was stored (can be null).

I defined my class as

```
class Document(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'documents'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
    original_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('documents.id'))
    original = relationship('Document', foreign_keys= original_id)
    
    first_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('documents.id'))
    first = relationship('Document', foreign_keys= first_id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name} ({self.id})'
```

But when I test it as follows:

```
d1 = Document(name='Dee one')
d2 = Document(name='Dee two')
d1.original.append(d2) # d1 has for original document d2
```

I am surprised by the implementation in terms of ids stored in what row (after committing)

```
>>> d1.original_id
None
>>> d2.original_id
1
>>> d1.original
[Dee two (2)]
>>> d2.original
[]
```

I wanted d1.original_id to hold 2 (the index for Dee two).

Obviously I am doing something wrong, but I am struggling to understand what. It seems I am ending up with a many to one relation but in the wrong direction.

I am using SQLAlchemy 1.3.5

Comment: In a one-to-many relationship the foreign key value for the parent object is stored in the child object. Notice that the original_id is stored in d2 , but d1.original (correctly) returns the d2 object.

Comment: Yes I but want a many to one relationship, and cannot figure out how to do this in this case.

Comment: One-to many and many-to-one are the same thing. They both involve one parent object with zero or more child objects. Parent has a one-to-many relationship with Child, and Child has many-to-one with Parent. In your case d1 is the child, and d2 is the parent.

Comment: I had found that solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649385/many-to-one-relationship-with-sqlalchemy-in-the-same-table but it only works for one link/pointer/relation. When there are multiple ones, SQLAlchemy complains. Hence my example with 2 fields original and field. But I have finally found a solution. I'll write it down. Many thanks for your remarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally, I wanted to have a class that contains 2 nullable pointers to other Nodes. To make the relationship clearer, let's call the class Person, and the links Father and Mother. Every person has at most a known Father and a known Mother.

So following the docs, I created the class as

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
    father_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    father = relationship('Person')
```

When doing so, the father relationship is 1-to-many, i.e. a Person can have many fathers, and a father can be only the father of 1. Which is not what is expected.

Following [Many to One relationship with SQLAlchemy in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649385/many-to-one-relationship-with-sqlalchemy-in-the-same-table) I found a way to make that a 1 to many relationship. Enter the `remote_side` parameter:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
    father_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    father = relationship('Person', remote_side=id)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now the relationship is as expected. However with multiple links (father and mother), this fails again. I.e. if I refine the class as:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
    father_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    father = relationship('Person', remote_side= id)
    
    mother_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    mother = relationship('Person', remote_side= id)
```

SQLAlchemy fails with an "AmbiguousForeignKeysError". The solution is then to specify what field is used to link to father and mother, as follows:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
    father_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    father = relationship('Person', remote_side= id, foreign_keys=father_id)
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
    mother_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'))
    mother = relationship('Person', remote_side= id, foreign_keys=mother_id)
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now that works as expected.

So in some way, this is an extension of the solution provided in [Many to One relationship with SQLAlchemy in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649385/many-to-one-relationship-with-sqlalchemy-in-the-same-table)

Many thanks Gord Thomson for your remarks.