# Flask + SQLalchemy one to many relationship within the same table not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a table in SQLAlchemy which has a one to many relationship within the same table. What I currently have is a dog class and I want a dog to be able to link to multiple children and I also want the children to be able to link back to their parents. I am currently using an SQLite database if that makes a difference

There have been some similar posts on this topic, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775701/one-to-many-relationship-on-same-table-in-sqlalchemy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649385/many-to-one-relationship-with-sqlalchemy-in-the-same-table), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355890/sqlalchemy-multiple-foreign-keys-in-one-mapped-class-to-the-same-primary-key). I have also tried using the documentation on [Adjacency List Relations](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/self_referential.html#self-referential), but I have not been able to find any solution that is working for me.

Here is my current code:

```
class Dog(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    birthday = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True)
    sex = db.Column(db.String(64))
    comments = db.Column(db.String(1000))

    fathered = db.relationship("Dog", backref = db.backref("father", remote_side=[id]))
    mothered = db.relationship("Dog", backref = db.backref("mother", remote_side=[id]))
    father_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dog.id'))
    mother_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dog.id'))
```

When I try to run my flask app I am met with this error

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Dog.fathered - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

Based on that error I also tried supplying a list of foreign keys to the relationship, like this

```
fathered = db.relationship("Dog", backref = db.backref("father", remote_side=[id]), foreign_keys = [id])
mothered = db.relationship("Dog", backref = db.backref("mother", remote_side=[id]), foreign_keys = [id])
```

But that also led to an error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Dog.fathered - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, apologies if I am missing something simple, or if there is a much simpler way to do this that I don't know, thank you.

Comment: You changed `db.relationship("Dog", …)` to `db.relationship("Fish", …)` ?

Comment: My bad, I also have a similar one for fish that has the same problem, so accidently copied the wrong piece of code, thanks for pointing it out, have fixed the typo now.

Comment: Try `fathered = db.relationship("Dog", backref=db.backref("father", remote_side=[id]), foreign_keys=[father_id])`

Comment: I thought I'd tried that before, but was getting an error, but turns out I was just getting a stupid error because of the way it was ordered, so that I was trying to use father_id before I had declared it. So it now seems to run without errors once I put fathered and mothered below the respective ids. I will need to do some more tests later to check it is functioning correctly then will update with the answer if it works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I thought and was something I thought I tried. You need to set the foreign keys of fathered and mothered to father_id and mother_id respectivley rather than just the id.
So this is the solution code that seems to be working:

```
father_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dog.id'))
mother_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('dog.id'))
fathered = db.relationship("Dog", foreign_keys = [father_id], backref = db.backref("father", remote_side=[id]))
mothered = db.relationship("Dog", foreign_keys = [mother_id], backref = db.backref("mother", remote_side=[id]))
```

Also, obviously make sure to move fathered and mothered below the father_id and mother_id, otherwise you won't be able to use the id's before they have been declared.

Thanks a lot to the comments on the post for helping with this one!