# How can i create table with self relation for categorize products in flask SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create a table with self-relation like this...

```
group_id | title  | parent_id
-------- | -----  | ---------
   1     |mobile  |   null
   2     |Sony    |    1
   3     |Samsung |    1
   4     |Laptop  |   null
   5     |ASUS    |    4
   6     |Dell    |    4
```

So **group_id** is the **primary key** of the table and parent_id is the foreign key. How should I modify this class **Flask SQL Alchemy**?

```
class ProductGroup(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "product_group"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(150), unique = True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, title, parent_id):
        self.title = title
        self.parent_id = parent_id


    def __repr__(self):

        return '<ProductGroup: {}>'.format(self.title)
```

Also, how can I give a relation this table and my product table? Below is my product table. I want to create category table for this table.

```
class Product(db.Model):
    """
        Create Product Table
    """
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    summary = db.Column(db.String(512))
    features = db.Column(db.String(256))
    description = db.Column(db.String(1024))
    thumbnail = db.Column(db.String(128))
    picture = db.Column(db.String(128))
    video = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __init__(self, name, summary, features, description, thumbnail, picture, video):
        self.name = name
        self.summary = summary
        self.features = features
        self.description = description
        self.thumbnail = thumbnail
        self.picture = picture
        self.video = video

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Product: {}>'.format(self.name)
```

> Please don't hesitate to give a better solution for categorizing products and posts tables.

Comment: I don't like the table in the first place :p

The so called **foreign key** is pointing to the same table. Not sure why you are doing this way

Comment: @Nabin Hi, I want to create dynamic categorize system in my database. When ever the user wants to create a new category and point to its parent, he can do with this table.

Comment: You can check out from this answer. [sqlalchemy self referencing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638217/sqlalchemy-mapping-self-referential-relationship-as-one-to-many-declarative-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For self reference you have to use relationship with the remote_side parameter to support many-to-one relationship.

```
parent_id = relationship("ProductGroup", remote_side=[id])
```

You can read more here: [enter link description here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/self_referential.html)

Comment: in flask-sqlalchemy its better to write `parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('product_group.id'))` to creating column then create relation between them `parent = db.relationship("ProductGroup", remote_side=[id])`

Comment: I create my table, but I have a problem with loading my parent's children when want to load children into my table. I used `parent = db.relationship('ProductCategory', remote_side=[id], uselist=False, backref='childs')` but how can i access in jinja parent attribute?

Answer (score -1):

At first, please set database records as follows to your `product_group` table.

[image]

And, please fix your code as follows.

```
class ProductGroup(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "product_group"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(150), unique = True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    group = db.relationship("ProductGroup", primaryjoin="ProductGroup.id==ProductGroup.parent_id", foreign_keys='ProductGroup.id')


    def __init__(self, title, parent_id):
        self.title = title
        self.parent_id = parent_id


    def __repr__(self):

        return '<ProductGroup: {}>'.format(self.title)
```

and, you can access `group` attribute as follows.

```
product_group = ProductGroup.query.get(2)
print(product_group.group)
```

you will get

`[<ProductGroup: mobile>]`

Is this what you want?

Incidentally, if you define `group` attribute of `product_group` as follows,

```
group = db.relationship("ProductGroup", primaryjoin="ProductGroup.id==ProductGroup.parent_id", foreign_keys='ProductGroup.id', uselist=False)
```

you will get value as object not array.