# SQLAlchemy One-to-Many relationship in single table- declarative

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have category and sub-category, I want to populate parent with child categories. How should I do?

```
class Category(Base):
       __tablename__ = 'category'
       id = Column(UUIDType, primary_key=True)
       organisation_id = Column(UUIDType)
       category_name = Column(String(50))
       parent_category_id = Column(UUIDType, ForeignKey("category.id"))
       parent_category = relationship("Category", backref='category', 
                   remote_side=parent_category_id)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy - Mapping self-referential relationship as one to many (declarative form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638217/sqlalchemy-mapping-self-referential-relationship-as-one-to-many-declarative-f)

Comment: Populate _from_ datebase, or populate _the_ database using the model?